# How to preserve object property when ConvertBack in IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a datagrid that looks something like this:

```
Name       | Day1 | Day2 | ... | Day31
--------------------------------------
Employee 1 | M    | M,N  | ... | N
```

The datagrid is bounded to an `ObservableCollection`, the `ObservableCollection` contains a property of `Employee` and `List<Schedule>`, each column is bounded to a `List<Schedule>` the list will have 0 to 2 item,

the Schedule class is :

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public char[] EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public char WorkCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public int PermitId { get; set; }
    public int CompensationId { get; set; }
}
```

I use `IValueConverter` to convert `List<Schedule>`'s WorkCode to string, so I can display it on the datagrid, however, I have been struggling to convert back the string to `List<Schedule>` if I edit <strike>or add new</strike> schedule, I need to preserve other property like EmployeeId, EffectiveDate.

**EDIT:**
If new data is added everything is `default` except WorkCode.

Comment: How do you edit the schedule?

Comment: directly edit the cell.

Comment: So if you add a new one, where do the extra properties come from?

Comment: EmployeeId is taken from row, EffectiveDate is column index, everyting else is default to null.